# How to Install python packages on a virtualenv using Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, virtualenv

I am not able to launch gunicorn I am getting this error

error:

```
fatal: [172.105.102.110]: FAILED! => {
   "changed":false,
   "cmd":"/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn -D --chdir /myproject --error-logfile /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1593463703.788082-353660-248038870081082/gunicorn.temp.error.log --pid /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1593463703.788082-353660-248038870081082/gunicorn.temp.pid wsgi",
   "msg":"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn'",
   "rc":2
}
```

do_tutorial.yml

```
---
- hosts: DigitialOceanExample
  become: yes
  tasks: 
  - name: Update apt-get repo and cache
    apt: 
      update_cache: yes 
      force_apt_get: yes 
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - name: Install a list of packages
    apt:
      pkg:
      - python3-pip
      - python3-dev
      - build-essential
      - libssl-dev
      - libffi-dev
      - python3-setuptools
      - python3-venv

  - name: ensure a directory exists or create it
    file: 
      path: /myproject
      state: directory

  - name: Manually create the initial virtualenv
    command:
      cmd: python3 -m venv /myproject/myprojectenv
      creates: "/myproject/myprojectenv"

  - name: "install python packages with the local instance of pip"
    shell: "pip3 install wheel flask gunicorn"

  - name: copy file to server
    copy: 
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /myproject
    loop:
      - ./myproject.py

  - name: Install ufw
    apt:
      name: ufw
      update_cache: true

  - name: "Allow port 5000"
    shell:  "ufw allow 5000"

  - name: copy file to server
    copy: 
      src: ./wsgi.py
      dest: /myproject 

  # - name: "starting gunicorn"
  #   shell: "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app"

  - name: run gunicorn on a virtualenv
    gunicorn:
      app: 'wsgi'
      chdir: '/myproject'
      venv: '/myproject/myprojectenv'
```

myproject.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

wsgi.py

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

hosts

```
[DigitialOceanExample]
PPP.PPP.PPP.PPP (redacted for StackOverFlow question)
```

command

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory  do_tutorial.yml
```

I am trying to replicate [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) using Ansible but I am getting an error with my virtualenv

Comment: I guess you should activate your venv to update your PATH env var or use absolute path to execute the pip `/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/pip3` of your newly created venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are installing with global pip instead of inside your virtual env.
Try with absolute path of pip3 in your newly created venv:

```
  - name: "install python packages with the local instance of pip"
    shell: "/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/pip3 install wheel flask gunicorn"
```

Answer (score 1):

The builtin Ansible [pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) supports this through the parameter `virtualenv`.

In your example:

```
- name: install python packages with the local instance of pip
  pip:
    name:
      - wheel
      - flask
      - gunicorn
    virtualenv: '/myproject/myprojectenv'
  become: yes
```

That should allow you to achieve the same without needing to use the `shell` module.

Comment: > _now supports_ - in fact, supported for [at least 8 years](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/cd42f736625151e987752307163607438e491e57/lib/ansible/modules/core/packaging/pip#L49). This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks, I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The above example given by Marsu works fine.

Just in case if anyone wants to execute the playbook on remote machine via Jenkins job, then you need to switch to the absolute path first and afterwards install the packages or requirements.txt

For example:

```
  - name: "install python packages with the local instance of pip"
shell: "cd /myproject && myprojectenv/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt"
```